# Bulk edit-tag for Google Reader

Tags: google-reader

How to bulk edit tag of the google reader item ?
Now I'm using /reader/api/0/edit-tag to edit tags, but it's very slow to update tags for all items (in loop).

Dow you know any way to send tags for many items at once? 
Possible solution looks like using some threads to send these requests to Google Reader Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include multiple i= and s= in the same post.  just make sure that as you add a new i= you add the corresponding s= for that item **even if you've already included the s= for that exact same stream previously** (this is really important, or you'll get a 400 error when making the call).  I was doing batches of 10 with my code, I'm sure you can do more but I don't know the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Could a working URL for marking all items as read be posted?

I have tried:

```
<?php echo 'http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?'.'s=feed%2F'.urlencode('http://feeds.feedburner.com/filehippo').'&i='.urlencode('tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/c7701cf414f3539e').'&a=user%2F-%2Flabel%2Fread'.'&T=bbi44C5CQzjzM43yKUPwnA'; ?>
```

but I just keep getting a 400 error back.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, url looks something like http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?ac=edit-tags&T=<your token>&a=user/-/starred&i=<I>&s=<S>&i=<I>&s=<S>&i=<I>&s=<S>&i=<I>&s=<S>, where <I> is post id in form "tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/......" and <S> is feed id in form "tag:google.com,2005:reader/feed/http......"